# Updating an AD UserPrincipal that has been extended with custom properties

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm stuck with AD again. Can anyone please point me in the direction of an example of how to update a UserPrincipal (C#) that has been extended using the [DirectoryProperty("Title")] style properties?

I can create the user fine, but when I retrieve him, he is a UserPrincipal again, and not my extended class. I've tried constructing my extended class like this

```
ADUserClassExtensions userExt = new ADUserClassExtensions(ctx, userOfInterest.SamAccountName, "******", true);
```

Hoping that it would let me set the properties and then save it. But it (rightly) complains that the user already exists because I am doing a Save() ,and I can't see an Update() method on there.

What's the recommended way to do this? Googled a bit and can't find anything.

Many thanks

Comment: Here is a sample to do that by using extensibility call, as it's [shown in this other article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855328/adding-address-information-to-active-directory-users/5857811#5857811).

Answer (score 0):

In the extending class:

```
public static new ADUserClassExtensions GetPrincipalByIdentity(PrincipalContext ctx, string identityValue) 
{
    return (ADUserClassExtensions) Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(ctx, typeof(ADUserClassExtensions), identityValue);  
}
```